# FullCalendar.io not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

So I've followed a tutorial on full calendar within my asp.net mvc application.

My Calendar controller:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    namespace Bookings.Controllers
    {
        public class CalendarController : Controller
        {
            BookingsModel.ModelBookings db = new BookingsModel.ModelBookings();
            // GET: Calendar
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public JsonResult GetEvents() {
                using (BookingsModel.ModelBookings db = new BookingsModel.ModelBookings()) {


              var events = db.Events.ToList();
                return new JsonResult { Data = events, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The index view of the calendar controller:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    <div id="calendar"></div>


    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

    <!-- qTip -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/3.0.3/jquery.qtip.min.css" />

    <!-- Full Calendar -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.9.1/fullcalendar.print.css" media="print" />

    @section scripts{
        <script src="~/Content/fullcalendar-3.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Content/fullcalendar-3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var events = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Calendar/GetEvents",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                            events.push({
                                title: v.Subject,
                                description: v.Description,
                                start: moment(v.Start),
                                end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                                color: v.ThemeColor,
                                allDay: v.IsFullDay
                            })

                        })
                        Generatealendar(events);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert('failed');
                    }
                })

                function FenerateCalendar(events) {
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                        contentHeight: 400,
                        defaultDate: new Date(),
                        timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                        header: {
                            Left: 'prev, next today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay, agenda'
                        },
                        eventLimit: true,
                        eventColor: '#378006',
                        events: events
                    })
                }
            })
        </script>
    }
    </head>
</html>
```

and finally my `Events.cs` file:

```
public class Events
{
    [Key]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
    public String Subject { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public String ThemeColor { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFullDay { get; set; }
}
```

At this point in the tutorial when ran I should see the full calendar with one entry.

I run as follows: http://localhost:35080/Calendar/GetEvents

but I simply get the event viewing as follows:

```
[{
    "EventID": 1,
    "Subject": "Birthday of a friend",
    "Description": "Birthday",
    "start": "\/Date(1498456800000)\/",
    "End": "\/Date(1498467600000)\/",
    "ThemeColor": "green",
    "IsFullDay": true
}]
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Someone said it may be because i was not logging into my application before loading the calendar view, however its the same when logged in.

The error I'm receiving in the debug window is:

```
Index:103 Uncaught ReferenceError: Generatealendar is not defined
    at Object.success (Index:103)
    at i (VM52 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM52 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
    at A (VM52 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (VM52 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4)
```

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mvc+json+date+format&oq=mvc+json+da&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3j69i57j69i59.10528j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to understand the issue with the dates (its easier to just send a collection of a view model or anonymous objects containing the formatted dates as strings)

Comment: "Someone said it may be because i was not logging into my application "...what makes you (or them) think that would affect the way the dates are formatted???

Comment: Anyway, what version of MVC are you using? Which Javascript serialiser are you using? JSON.NET does not serialise dates like that, that's the old MS way of doing it, should be long gone. To work round it though, momentJS can parse it: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/ . Your code looks like it's doing that, so it's a bit unclear what the problem is? Does it display the events, or not? Although why the tutorial didn't get you to make the JSON in the way fullCalendar expects from the start, instead of having to translate it in the Javascript, is also a mystery.

Comment: BTW you are including the fullCalendar CSS in your page twice, for no apparent reason.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you for this.  I have tested it quickly this morning and must be getting something wrong as its not worked, its probably because I've coded something incorrect, I will keep you updated.

Comment: @ADyson regarding the logging in, it was a comment someone put on a previous full calendar post on here, it did not work.  The way its displaying it in the browser is exactly what I have put in the last code snippet, no calendar on the screen just simply the code??? I realised that after I had posted this that I put the CSS in twice, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: "The way its displaying it in the browser is exactly what I have put in the last code snippet, no calendar on the screen just simply the code". That suggests you are simply visiting the "/Calendar/GetEvents" URL directly in your browser? You need to go to the View URL (e.g. "Calendar/Index") in your browser. This will display the calendar. Fullcalendar will then make a separate ajax request to the GetEvents method once the view has loaded. If you visit the JSON endpoint directly in your browser then of course naturally it will only display the JSON. Not sure why you thought to do that

Comment: @ADyson When I run the index view of the calendar controller I just get a blank page - the calendar has not been imported properly? I have followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wA-Iy6ThYz4.  I can not see why it would not import correctly, I have put the correct references at the right places

Comment: check your browser's console (in the Developer Tools, press F12 to open them) for errors. I don't see anywhere you've loaded jQuery into your view.

Comment: @ADyson I have included JQuery but am getting the error above, I've added into the original post, what do you think?

Comment: You can google that error message 100 times over, but to save you time I'll tell you that it means a variable or function with that name does not exist. Indeed, that's the case. You're trying to call a function "Generatealendar" but in the code your function is called "FenerateCalendar". Ironically, both of them are spelled incorrectly. It's simply a case of two typing errors. I think you need to get a bit smarter with checking your code, and also learning how to debug.

Comment: @ADyson You're right, I have been an idiot and naming things incorrectly.  It works find now! Thank you very much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, As said above it appears that the function name 'GenerateCalendar' is spelled incorrectly twice.  This is what caused the calendar not to be generated within the index view.